# How to prove the Parseval's Formula?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

How to prove Parseval's Formula:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \phi(x) \bar{\psi}(x) dx = (2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{\phi}(\xi)\bar{\hat{\psi}}(\xi) d \xi,
$$
where $ \phi(x), \xi(x)\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) $. And for a function $ f(x)\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R^n}) $, define its Fourier transform to be
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{-i<x, \xi>}f(x)dx.
$$
And $ \bar{\psi}(x) $ represents the complex conjugate of function $ \psi(x) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will adopt the following convention for the Fourier transform (i.e. no factors of $2\pi$ for the back transformation):

$$\phi(\xi)=(2\pi)^{n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{\phi}(x)e^{-i x \xi}\, dx$$

Then
$$\langle\phi,\psi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \phi(x) \bar{\psi}(x) dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \phi(x) \left(\overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{\psi}(\xi)e^{i x \xi}\, d\xi} \right)dx=\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \phi(x) \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\bar{\hat{\psi}}(\xi)e^{-i x \xi}\, d\xi \,dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}  \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\phi(x)e^{-i x \xi}\, dx \right)\bar{\hat{\psi}}(\xi)d\xi\\
=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\hat{\phi}(\xi)\bar{\hat{\psi}}(\xi) d \xi=(2\pi)^{-n}\langle\hat{\phi},\hat{\psi}\rangle$$.

This would typically be referred to as the Plancharel theorem, rather than Parseval's formula.

Comment: It should be added that for $\phi,\psi \in L^2$, the integrand $F(x,\xi) = \phi(x)\bar{\hat\psi(\xi)} e^{-ix\xi}$ is not absolutely integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ and hence Fubini's theorem cannot be applied. However the formal calculation does work for Schwartz functions, which may be all you need. (One way of defining the Fourier transform on $L^2$ is to prove Plancharel for Schwartz functions, this implies $L^2$-continuity, which allows for a unique bounded extension to all of $L^2$).

Comment: Thank you! The ideas of Fourier transform and its inversion are interchangeable all the time and changing the order of integration are so helpful and really used a lot!